# materialized view manual refresh

Tags: google-bigquery

I was experimenting with Big Query materialized view manual refresh but when I try to call the procedure as per the documentation

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CALL BQ.REFRESH_MATERIALIZED_VIEW('my-project-id.my-dataset-name.mv_name')"
```

I get back :

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'project-id:bqjob_r508c7d13330d5fcd_0000017801fd2694_1': Not found: Dataset my-project-id.my-dataset-name was not found in location US at [1:6]
```

my-project-id is my GCP project, my-dataset-name is the dataset which is not in the US.

Note I get the same error when using the Query window from the web console.

I haven't been able to find any system documentation on the sp itself though it seems to only take 1 argument, but I hoped it would be able to figure out the location to run via the project id and dataset as supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're don't support routing for materialized view refresh right now. If this would be valuable to you please submit a feature request in our [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0). In the meantime you can refresh your views by explicitly [picking a location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location) in the UI or using the --location flag on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use  "`" instead of "'" around the dataset.table name.
Try below

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CALL BQ.REFRESH_MATERIALIZED_VIEW(`my-project-id.my-dataset-name.mv_name`)"
```

in BQ console.

```
CALL BQ.REFRESH_MATERIALIZED_VIEW(`my-project-id.my-dataset-name.mv_name`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the location where your refresh job should run. Choose the region where you view and table is located.

[image]
[image]